# jQuery Float Number

Tags: jquery, string

I have problem with following calculation:

```
$result = $a + $b + ($c * $d - $e) * $f + $g;
```

The formula may more complicated.  I found some variables are treated as String instead of Number, therefore the result is wrong.

For the following code:

```
$result = parseFloat($a) + parseFloat($b) + (parseFloat($c) * parseFloat($d) - parseFloat($e)) * parseFloat($f) + parseFloat($g);
```

It seems right.  However, is there any good way to do it, instead of write parseFloat() function for each of the variable?

Comment: Provide sample examples/values of your variables.

Comment: Some variables? Either all or none. How can there be some? What is the difference between them if some are treated one way and some other?

Comment: multiply all of them by 1.0

Comment: If there is a solution, it lies in how your page or your variables are defined. There's no general solution for this apart bad hacks like replacing `parseFloat($a)` with `+$a`.

Comment: For example if the variables like:  $a = $("#a").val(); $b = $("#b").val(); $c = $("#c").val(); ...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `+`

http://jsfiddle.net/2yrMc/

```
var $b = "0.785";

alert(typeof +$b);
```